# Object not found in R when trying to create a table from a csv dataset

Tags: r

I'm using RStudio to create glm's of a csv dataset and I'm really new to R (Using it for a Uni assignment). Quick summary, it's looking at some motor claim data. I've read.csv the dataset into R;

```
Motor <- read.csv("motor.csv", quote="", header=TRUE)
```

then am trying to run

```
(ClaimsTab <- table(Claims))
```

to create a table to see the frequency of different claim amounts.

'Claims' is a header in my CSV file and there's no spelling mistakes but am returned with

```
Error in table(Claims) : object 'Claims' not found
```

I've attempted to attach a picture of my dataset.

[motor dataset picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5WH9.png)

What am I doing wrong? I imported a different file earlier and the table() function was working fine.

Comment: Hard to know without `dput(head(Motor, 10))`, however you can always hash an specific column by using `$` , I suggest you can try : `ClaimsTab <- table(Motor$Claims)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your dataframe object is Motor.
To access a column in a dataframe in base R you do: Motor$Claims
This should work:
`ClaimsTab <- table(Motor$Claims)`